# Running unit tests from currently opened file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

Is there any way to have IntelliJ run the current MyTest.java file I'm looking at?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah, you can either:

1. Right click on the file and go to

   > Run 'MyTest'
2. Use the key binding: if the *caret* is in a method on that method will be run

   - on a Mac: it's <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
   - elsewhere: it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: For those that want to remap: it is Run Context Configuration (and Debug Context Configuration).

Comment: To run all tests in a file, place cursor outside any test method and press `right click -> Run ...` or press keyboard shortcut (shortcut for the current system should be displayed next to the `Run` option).

Comment: For those coming here on windows with a version 2020.2 the shortcut for is `Ctrl+Shift+F10`

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer did not work for me on a MacOS running Android Studio 2.1.13 .

After looking up the "Run Context Configuration" action mentioned by @ShawnFumo's comment, I found Ctrl + Shift + R which ended up working.